# Request for reference to the (inexact?) quote "The introduction of coordinates to geometry was an act of aggression"

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I heard this quote years ago in a class but I can't find any reference to it or who said it and I'd greatly appreciate any information behind it, as I remember it, it goes;

> "The introduction of coordinates to geometry was an act of aggression"

I don't think it's exactly that but it's something in that vein. Sorry if this is vague but I can't seem to find any reference to it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be better for https://hsm.stackexchange.com -- but see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493341/what-exactly-did-hermann-weyl-mean

Comment: Sounds similar to a quote by [Weyl](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493341/what-exactly-did-hermann-weyl-mean).

Comment: @BarryCipra probably, thank you

Comment: @twosigma That's it, you got it, the quote is "The introduction of numbers as coordinates is an act of violence." put that as an answer and I'll accept it, thank you very much

Comment: @Barry you wanna put it? I tried and it says trivial answer converted to comment :)

Comment: or actually I guess Barry Cipra got it first, idk, sorry you both answered it and I appreciate it, thank you very much

Comment: @twosigma I don't think a link and a name should be considered trivial considering it answers my question, though it is a trivial question

Comment: It's probably because my answer is too short or because I literally copy-pasted my comment. I could have made it longer but Barry's comment is first so he can answer it.

Comment: @AR., I'm not sure how twosigma found it, but I found the link by googling on the quote as you inexactly remembered it. Somehow Google was able to get from your wording to the exact quote.

Comment: @BarryCipra To be honest I haven't googled it for awhile but I remember trying before and getting nothing, I just googled the "quote" too and found the question you linked to so I probably jumped the gun asking this question, but I appreciate the help nonetheless and if you want to put your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again

Comment: I just googled it as well and that MSE post shows up.

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Comment: @twosigma, a little more googling got me to Weyl's original version (in English translation, at least). I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quote originates in Hermann Weyl's *Philosophy of Mathematics and Natural Science* (pg. 90). The exact quote is a little less pithy than it has come to be customarily rendered:

> The introduction of numbers as coordinates by reference to the
> particular division scheme of the open one-dimensional continuum is an
> act of violence whose only practical vindication is the special
> calculatory manageability of the ordinary number continuum with its
> four basic operations.

The pithy version may derive from *Gauge Fields, Knots and Gravity* by John Baez and Javier P. Muniain, published in 1994, where Weyl's quote appears on page 49 as

> The introduction of numbers as coordinates [...] is an
> act of violence whose only practical vindication is the special
> calculatory manageability of the ordinary number continuum with its
> four basic operations.

followed by an article by Hans-Joachim Baues in *Handbook of Algebraic Geometry*, published in 1995, where it's further shortened (pg. 4) to

> "The introduction of numbers as coordinates [...] is an
> act of violence..."

The ellipses have been dropped in various online sites that compile quotes without sourcing them, including [this one](https://quotefancy.com/hermann-weyl-quotes), where you can download these and other of Weyl's words superimposed on various "wallpaper" backgrounds. It might be of interest to see if the OP's version of the quote, with "aggression" replacing "violence," gets picked up and reproduced in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much!