# The meaning of "The introduction of numbers as coordinates is an act of violence"

Tags: soft-question

I found the quote

> The introduction of numbers as coordinates is an act of violence.

from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/7377/99469) from https://mathoverflow.net is very interesting. Unfortunately, I can not understand it. I asked for elaboration below that answer and have not received any response for a long time.

Could you please elaborate on this quote? Thank you so much!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493341/what-exactly-did-hermann-weyl-mean might help

Comment: Thank you so much @BarryCipra. I don't delete this question. Instead, I close it. This is because my question title is easier to search than the one you suggested.